# How create PDF/A1 on C# with iTextsharp 5.5

Tags: c#, itext, pdfa

I am developing a function that converts a .doc file to Pdf/A1 (ISO 19005-1) in C# with the iTextsharp 5.5.13 library. I'm creating it based on the following documentation: [Concepts](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing/1-zugferd-core-concepts), [Pdf/A1 Java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/es/examples/archiving-and-accessibility-itext5/pdfa-1), [Pdf C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/661704/Create-pdf-A-using-itextsharp) and [Pdf/A3 Java](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/zugferd/browse/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/zugferd/pdfa/PdfA3a.java)

The problem I have is that some methods and classes (PdfAWriter and PdfAConformanceLevel) seem not to be in this version of iTextsharp.
Has anyone been able to do this step that can indicate me some link with the documentation to create Pdf/A1 with the library iTextsharp 5.5.13 for C#, or in some other way to create a Pdf/A1 from a .doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you use the *maintenance* release of an old iText version instead of the latest version iText 7.1.2? We don't use the name iTextSharp anymore; iTextSharp was renamed to iText for .NET two years ago. See the [iText 7 download page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/downloads).

This being said: if you go to the [iText 5 download page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextsharp-net), you'll discover that iText 5 consists of different packages, one of which is called `itextsharp.pdfa`. It seems that you overlooked this package.

If you use Nuget, do:

```
Install-Package itextsharp.pdfa
```

And you'll be able to use the `PdfAWriter` and `PdfAConformanceLevel` class. However, I would recommend you to use [iText 7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/) instead.

Comment: Hi Bruno,
Thanks for the prompt response. We are using version 5.5.13 mainly for the type of license.
And you're right, I had installed only iTextSharp, not the other packages, my mistake.

Comment: Please explain "We are using version 5.5.13 mainly for the type of license." The license of 5.5.13 is the AGPL; the license of 7.1.2 is AGPL. Why would your prefer iText 5.5.13 over iText 7.1.2 when they have the same license???

Comment: By the way: you are not allowed to distribute a closed source application that uses iText 5. The AGPL requires that you make your own source code open under the same license. If you can't do that, purchasing a commercial license is required.

Comment: I thought that itext 7 was under another type of license, mainly because the first thing you see is that they offer only one month of trial version to test it.
Now I am using version 7.
Which leads me to another question, is it possible to convert a .doc to Pdf/A1 with that version and if so, can you guide me with some documentation or example in C#?

Comment: iText doesn't do Word to PDF conversion.